# Include NPM modules in typescript output (--module System.js)

Tags: typescript, systemjs

I am converting a project from ES6 to Typescript. The TSConfig file sets the following options:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "system",
        "out": "qqq.js",
        "allowJs": true,
}
```

In my code, I import NPM modules living in `node_modules`. This was also what I did prior to using Typescript.

```
import React from 'react'; // This is an NPM module.
// . . .
```

Running the typescript compiler produces an *almost* usable *.js bundle, but it is missing all of the NPM modules.

**How can I configure Typescript to include all of my NPM dependencies (not just local files) when building a System.js bundle?**

Comment: I don't think this is supported yet when you use modules. I usually compile them to CommonJS for Node and then use Browserify to bundle them into one file for the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create your deployment bundle yourself. The two helpfull samples for you to have a look at are:

[Angular2 Seed](https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed)

This one is great place to start looking for the solution. Dot not bother that it is for angular2. It still does exactly what you are looking for - compile TS files and prepare bundle with all referenced node_modules included.

If you would like to try bundle creation with webpack, you are welcome to checkout this identical sample:

[WebPack angular2 starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript won't bundle NPM dependencies for you, you'll need to use something like [SystemJS Builder](https://github.com/systemjs/builder) for bundling.

Comment: My question was related to SystemJS. I have not heard of Webpack being used in conjunction with SystemJS (I was under the impression that they were competing solutions).
 Could you please explain how this would work in relation to SystemJS?

Comment: You're right, I was under the mistaken impression Webpack could handle anything, but for SystemJS you'd presumably use the SystemJS Builder to bundle your modules.